# Python+Selenium+PhantomJS. Waiting for proxy

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

The code is given proxy to using it through the PhantomJS  to load the page. But it happens that proxies are either too slow or does not work.
Tell me please how to make sure that the page is trying to open, but for example on the expiration of 20-30 seconds was issued a message that "The proxy does not work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.PhantomJS()
service_args = [
    '--proxy=10.10.20.20:3128',
    '--proxy-type=http',
    ]
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=service_args)
browser.get('http://check-host.net/ip')
browser.quit()
```

Maybe "Try....Catch..."
Help me plese.
Thank you advance!

Answer (score 1):

`try:
    <browser.get()>
    sleep(5)
 except Exception as e:
    print e`

Comment: Error: 
    <browser.get('http://check-host.net/ip')>
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: oh. that was only to suggest to use the code block . remove '<' '>'

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
import time
service_args = [
    '--proxy=10.10.20.20:3128',
    '--proxy-type=http',
    ]
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=service_args)
browser=webdriver.PhantomJS()
try:
browser.get('http://check-host.net/ip')
sleep(5)
print("Worked")
except:
print("Don't worked")
browser.get_screenshot_as_file('/var/www/html/img/testing8.png')
browser.quit()

Comment: well if you dont get the loaded page or screenshot and also no error, that means the proxy is slow / non-functional / blocked. i dont see any api in phantomjs browser ( dir(browser) ) which can give you status of proxy. but if proxy allows, you can execute a script on proxy and then find out if proxy is working before using it.

Comment: The whole algorithm should look like this: Page are trying to download through a proxy. Happened? He writes, "It works." It did not happen in 20 seconds? He writes," does not work "and exits the browser.

Comment: for timeout place a set_page_load_timeout before browser.get

`browser.set_page_load_timeout(3)`